# Proof of theorem 28.13 in "General Topology" by Willard

Tags: general-topology

From Willard S. General Topology.
I think I'm missing something.
In the function $F$, how does the value of $F(x)$ determined for $x\in K\setminus D$ such that $x\neq a,b,p$?
I get that $F$ extend $f$, but I don't understand how exactly it works.
can anyone help me?

[image: theorem 28.13 in "General Topology" by Willard]

Answer (score 0):

The procedure he describes ("But each point $p$ of $K$ other than $a$ or $b$ .. " etc.) defines $F(p)$ for all $p$ unequal to $a$ or $b$. He uses $p$ instead of $x$ (as he needs $x$ and $y$ to be "free" to use in his write-up).